# Is there a way to get submissions or a subreddit based on the flair using pushshift API?

Tags: python, reddit, praw, data-collection, flair

I looked through the documentation but I was not able to find how to retrieve submissions based on flair from a particular subreddit for a given time period, without using BigQuery.
Just using the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at this time according to the documentation.

Comment: No problem, please accept this as the correct answer if you can :)